# Convert an entire string value into ASCII number in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to convert the entered string value into an ASCII value to store into database as an array object. It is required as per the functional requirement.

Comment: Then go ahead and do that. Let us know if and when you run into an actual problem.

Comment: Characters (instances of `char`) have nearly nothing to do with "ASCII"; they are roughly Unicode Code points. Do  you want to convert a string into an array of characters or into an array of bytes. If the latter, you'll need to decide on an encoding (one possible encoding is ASCII  but it's unlikely that's what you want).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the below code -

```html
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string value = "Hello World";
            Console.WriteLine(value);

            int[] result = new int[value.Length];
            int index = 0;

            foreach (var c in value)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    result[index] = Convert.ToInt32(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    result[index] = ((int)c);
                }
                index++;
            }

            foreach (int i in result)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} ", i);
            }
        }
```

The if part is added due to consider if the string value contains any numerical value. That's why it will check either that particular character is digit or not. If digit then it will cast the value into Integeer type. Otherwise, else block will be called for all the characters value.

Comment: Actually, I want this type of result that internally split each character to convert it into an ASCII value and stores it in as an array. Your code snippet will fit my requirements. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: This code has several issues. 1) You can’t add to an array. 2) Add is spelled wrong. 3) `Convert.ToInt32` and `(int)` do the same. 4) `char.IsDigit` handles Unicode digits, not ASCII digits and a conversion to int will return the Unicode codepoint which can be any value between 0 and 1 million. That doesn’t seem what was intended. 5) The variable str is unused.

Comment: thanks for pointing issue in the solution. I have updated this.